# Tensorflow distributed training pause after each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am training a neural network in parallel on 2 GPUs using the Tensorflow MirroredStrategy. With a single GPU, each epoch takes 19 seconds to complete whereas with 2 GPUs, each epoch takes 13 seconds to finish. I am not surprised at this since I know the scaling is not perfect due to the all_reduce overhead for updating the variables during training.

However, after each epoch of the distributed training, there is a pause of about 8 seconds. When using a single GPU, this pause is less than 1 second. Does anyone know why there is such a long pause after each epoch when training distributed?

Alternatively, can anyone explain what happens differently in distributed training at the end of an epoch?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this had something to do with running TF in graph mode. By setting `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` the problem went away. This also fixed a memory leak that was causing issues, so perhaps the pause was being caused by TF making copies of something that I wasn't expecting.